# Difference in pipeline type

Tags: powershell

Why does:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-Service } -ComputerName SERVER01 | Get-Member
```

return TypeName: Deserialized.System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController

But:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-Service } -ComputerName SERVER01 | % { $_.GetType() }
```

returns a type `Name` of `PSObject` and `BaseType` of `System.Object`?

**Edit:** I understand that the object that comes back from `Invoke-Command` is Deserialized. It just seems odd that the same object is reported as a different type by `GetType()` and `Get-Member`.

```
PS C:\src\t> $gss = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-Service } -ComputerName SERVER01

PS C:\src\t> $gss[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     PSObject                                 System.Object

PS C:\src\t> $gss[0] | Get-Member

   TypeName: Deserialized.System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController
```

Comment: Get-Member and GetType() have different use cases and therefor use different methods to return the object type. GetType() is a .NET method and will return the type within the context of how it would be viewed in .NET and Get-Member is a PowerShell cmdlet and will return the type within the context of how it would be viewed in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a command that returns an object over a remote session (which you imply by using the `-ComputerName` parameter even if it is preformed against the same computer you ran the command from) PowerShell will convert the object to a `PSObject` that contains all properties of the original object but without any of its methods. You can verify when this is happening due to the Deserialized prefix returned by `Get-Member`. The reason this happens is because PowerShell cannot run a method on a remote object. You will see methods that can be run locally such as `ToString()`, however.

Only a handful of primitive types and almost-primitive types are truly brought across and will not receive this conversion. Below is not an extensive list but examples that have been given.

- Byte, SByte, Byte[]
- Int16, Int32, Int64, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64
- Decimal, Single, Double
- TimeSpan, DateTime, ProgressRecord
- Char, String, XmlDocument, SecureString
- Boolean, Guid, Uri, Version
- Enums

More on this behavior can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2010/01/07/how-objects-are-sent-to-and-from-remote-sessions/).

Comment: Maybe worth noting that `Get-Member` doesn't use reflection to extract the typename, but displays `$_.pstypenames[0]`

Comment: I am selecting this as the answer because this appears to be the way it works. PowerShell seems inconsistent on the returned type. It is reported by `Get-Member` as one type and by GetType() as a different type.